# window.close() dose'nt work script may close only the windows that were opened by it

Tags: javascript

I have an application which, after sending a form, directly closes the window page.
I have to login and after login, I am redirected to an another page where I fill out a form, and after sending the form the window page is closed automaticly.
I use this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('','_parent',''); 
    window.close();
</script>
```

but it not closes the page that is open after the login page.
Thank you

Comment: Because the window in this code is referring to the current page and not the new one which have just been open

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to open a new page and then later close it. When you are opening a new page, you also need to keep its reference in the current scope in order to have control over it. Try the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var newPage = window.open('','_parent',''); 
     newPage.close();
</script>
```

Comment: i have added this code in the page with the form but nothing happend.
to be redirected to the page i use header location method

Comment: window.close() must be in the same scope as that of the page you are trying to close. Can u put your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-yjb5rm?file=index.html

Comment: I checked the code and I see that you are using html embedded with php files. In this case I would suggest you to not use JavaScript for page redirect and close. Use php page redirect with data passing. You can do that by either post the form data via form-action="test.php" or pass temporary data via $_SESSION[]

Comment: When you are in test.php then next redirect can be based on your logic. For example, to go to logic page from home page, a simple button link with href="login.php" is enough. Then in login.php you can have a form and it can post to itself and when $_POST is not empty you can check the login details in database and try login. If login is success then redirect to another page with session user info. If login fails, show error message. If register button link is clicked, redirect to register.php and so on. I hope I was able to explain my logic.